# How long should I cook a carvery shoulder of lamb, and at what temperature?

Tags: roasting

I have a carvery shoulder of lamb joint weighing 1.906 kg. How long and at what temperature should I cook it?

Comment: Your question is too broad, you need to narrow it down. Do you want a braise or roast? If a roast do you want it rare, medium, or well? Is it bone-in or boneless?

Answer (score 2):

As long and as slowly as possible. In practical terms, place the shoulder in a roasting tin with some sliced onions, whole, unpeeled garlic cloves and rosemary. Cover the tin tightly with foil. Preheat your oven to its maximum temperature, place the lamb in, then turn it down to 150°C/300°F and cook for 4-5 hours. It should come out so tender that you can pull the bone out easily.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred method for joints of lamb is to brown it all over in a pan, and then cook it in lamb stock in a slow cooker for at least 8 hours.

It comes out so tender that the meat just falls off the bone.